# How to combine two selects with different where clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
select kota ,total, totalsum from 
(
SELECT  i.[Antam_Unit] as kota ,count(p.[Id_Pks_Pk])as total FROM [SIMPKBL].[dbo].[Pks_Pk] p join [SIMPKBL].[dbo].[Par_Unit_Antam] i on  i.Id_Unit_Antam = p.Id_Unit_Antam  group by i.[Id_Unit_Antam],i.Antam_Unit
UNION ALL
SELECT  i.[Antam_Unit] as kota , count(p.[Id_Proposal_Pk])as totalsum  FROM [SIMPKBL].[dbo].[Pks_Pk] p join [SIMPKBL].[dbo].[Par_Unit_Antam] i on  i.Id_Unit_Antam = p.Id_Unit_Antam where YEAR(p.Tanggal_Cetak_Pks_Pk) = '2012'   group by i.[Id_Unit_Antam],i.Antam_Unit 
) t
group by kota,total
```

I want an output like this:

```
kota total totalsum
A     12      4
B     16      5
```

Comment: It looks like the `total` and `totalsum` columns are coming from different queries.  You probably want to use a `join` to put the results together rather than a `union`.  A `union` requires that all of the rows have the same columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since the queries are so similar it appears that they can be combined into one `select`:

```
select i.[Antam_Unit] as kota,
  count(p.[Id_Pks_Pk]) as total,
  count( case when YEAR(p.Tanggal_Cetak_Pks_Pk) = '2012' then p.[Id_Proposal_Pk] else null end ) as totalsum
  FROM [SIMPKBL].[dbo].[Pks_Pk] p join [SIMPKBL].[dbo].[Par_Unit_Antam] i on  i.Id_Unit_Antam = p.Id_Unit_Antam
  group by i.[Id_Unit_Antam], i.Antam_Unit
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, the result you are looking for can be achieved using this simple statement:

```
SELECT  i.[Antam_Unit] as kota, 
count(p.[Id_Pks_Pk]) as total,
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(p.Tanggal_Cetak_Pks_Pk) = '2012' AND p.[Id_Proposal_Pk] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as totalsum  
FROM [SIMPKBL].[dbo].[Pks_Pk] p 
 join [SIMPKBL].[dbo].[Par_Unit_Antam] i 
 on  i.Id_Unit_Antam = p.Id_Unit_Antam 
group by i.[Id_Unit_Antam],i.Antam_Unit
```

Comment: if `p.[Id_Proposal_Pk]` is `NULL` then I think you'll produce a result different from the original query.